# Django model structure to allow 'test users'

Tags: python, django, database-design, django-models

I have a django application, using the basic `userprofile` extension of `django.contrib.auth.user` model. I would like to add 'test users' to the site, to allow individuals to view the site but not affect the rest of the users (for example, for demonstration purposes).

This is what it would entail:

```
1 - Allow that user to do everything a 'normal' user could do
2 - Hide that user from all searches (or places where the user may be 'viewed' by other users)
```

What would be a good way to accomplish this in the models? (I was thinking of setting `user.is_active=False`, but I run into some issues doing that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **best** approach would be to have a different copy of your web app with a different copy of a database.  You could then keep the two completely separate without having to go through incredible measures to filter access to different user groups for something that seems more like an administrative task than an actual value-added feature to your site.

With that lecture out of the way, I'd suggest using [user profiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) to add custom information.  You can add a boolean field, is_test_user, or something like that and then filter off of that for all the cases where you'd need to.

A good tutorial for this can be found [here](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/django-profile).

Comment: +1, wish I could upvote more than once though. 2 copies of the web app is the way to go for test users.